# Setting on click action for dynamically generated links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div of links that get dynamically generated.  I am trying to set the on click action of the links but it is not working.

Code:

```
$('#tags').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").html("hello");
});
```

The links in the tags div are generated by the following code:

```
$("#alpha_menu li").each(function() {
    $("#alpha_menu li a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('tags_script.php', {id: $(this).text()}, function(data) {
            $("#tags").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: `$("#alpha_menu li a").click` should just do the job of `$("#alpha_menu li").each(function() { $("#alpha_menu li a").click(`. You don't need the `.each`.

Comment: Update the listener to `$('#tags #alpha_menu li').on('click', 'a')`

Comment: The event delegation should work fine but the `.each` is certainly wrong here. You are binding multiple event handlers to each element.

Comment: @Phil: What makes you think there are multiple `#tags` elements?

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry, upon reading the code more thoroughly, I noticed my mistake :)

Comment: alpha_menu is not nested inside the tags div so changing the listener doesn't work.  And yeah i guess I don't need the .each call.

Comment: .on method supported only in jQuery 1.7+ What version you use? Have you some error in console?

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which replicates your problem. Otherwise I doubt we will be able to help you. There is not enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (outside document ready):

```
$(document).on('click', '#tags a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").html("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

> ```
> var attachLink = function(event){ 
>     event.preventDefault();
>     $.post('tags_script.php', {id: $(this).text()}, function(data) {
>         $('#tags').off();
>         $('#tags').html(data);
>         $('#tags').on('click', 'a', attachLink);
>
>         //console.log(attachLink);
>     });
> }
>
> $('#tags').on('click', 'a', attachLink);
> ```

Comment: The links are being generated correctly.  My problem is setting the click action for the links after they are generated.

Answer (score -1):

This is because at the moment when you set the events, the link not exists.
You should set the click event after the link exists

Comment: As you can see at the `.on('click', 'a', function(event) {...})` signature, the OP is using *event delegation*.